# What is "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root"?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, disk, disk-management

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 recently.
During the installation I did not create a separate partition for my home folder.
I also accidentally encrypted my home folder.
When i did

```
sudo df
```

I got the result as

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  455G  181G  251G  42% /
....
```

Why does this have a funny name instead of a normal '/dev/sdx'?

Please explain to me what this is?

Answer (score 33):

The `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` in place of a traditional `/dev/sdxN` block device just indicates that you chose to install the system using LVM2 *logical volume management*. See [What is LVM and what is it used for?](https://askubuntu.com/a/3833/178692)

Comment: I tried to install ubuntu with LVM option on windows hard drive with three partitions but canceled (didn't even begin) now I cannot see my partitions and using fdisk -l this ubuntu--vg-root` is shown, can I access my partitions and are my files still intact?