# How to find physical disks?

Tags: 20.04, disk, lvm

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 54.98 MiB, 57626624 bytes, 112552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 71.28 MiB, 74735616 bytes, 145968 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 29.9 MiB, 31334400 bytes, 61200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.99 GiB, 16072572928 bytes, 31391744 sectors
Disk model: IDSDM
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: C1D9C783-625F-47BA-8BA0-8B78019F9DCC

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624  3147775  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3147776 31389695 28241920 13.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 13.48 GiB, 14457765888 bytes, 28237824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I connect to a blackbox machine my friend gave me, so I want to check disk information.

Does the above command say there is only 1 physical disk with space only 14.99G? I hardly believe nowadays there is any disk with 14.99G space.

[What is "/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg--root"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/593755/what-is-dev-mapper-ubuntu-vg-root) says ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is something managed by lvm2.

Does it mean this blackbox machine has a second disk whose size is again amazing small at 13.48G?

Comment: It seems like an [SD card](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/en/poweredge-idsdm-whitepaper-en.pdf).

Comment: Yep. 15GB of space, split across three partitions. The `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` is a logical volume and consumes all of `/dev/sda3`. That system is probably itching for some proper storage ...

Comment: ```sudo lsblk``` can give you a nice tree of storage to show you what is where.