# FUBAR Fsckk'd Ubuntu Beyond All Repair?

Tags: boot, data-recovery

3TB WD AF[4096blks]Hdd ASUS P7P55d MoBo non-UEFI and 4GB ram.

I tried to install xp pro 64bit, but didn't complete because of Windoze not seeing the whole drive.  I installed Ubuntu 14.10 LTS and used the whole drive as ext4, no other partitions. Worked for months.

After some kernel upgrade, seemingly automatic, I get a 'missing OS' error on boot and cannot mount the drive.

Using tools from LiveCd, PartedMagic and SysRescueCd, I find I had corrupt superblock, overlapping partitions, bad geometry and other errors.  Searched the web for weeks now, trying every tip, trick and code until one suggested I fix my errors by changing to ext2 file system.  I used the code and fubar'd my inodes and journal and filesystem.

Is it possible to change back to ext4 without further damage?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sda
```

The size of this disk is 2.7 TiB (3000592982016 bytes). DOS partition   table format can not be used on drives for volumes larger than 2199023255040 bytes for 512-byte sectors. Use GUID partition table format (GPT).

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xa76529e9

Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *    505856 4295473150 4294967295   2T 83 Linux

sysrsccd gdisk -l output with lousy formatting
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.0

Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

---

Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory.

---

Disk /dev/sda: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): EC4893A3-AD27-473D-931C-50C03164D378
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 1565565806 sectors (746.5 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1          505856      4295473150   2.0 TiB     8300  Linux filesystem

Now I will try to type in the URL's that I have from a few days after the crash and today ( July19th)

[link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/11779238/

[link]http://paste.ubuntu.com/11907369/

Sorry about the mess.

Comment: Can you get us at least the output of `fdisk` command that we cann see what partition scheme do you have currently? And please reformat the text, it's way tooooo long!!!!

Comment: How can I do that from Ubuntu LiveCd? Right now I am on my brother's win7 laptop, testdisk searching on 3tb drive in tower, running LiveCd.

Comment: Post this also & preserve formatting so we can easily read it. `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: I found one of the url #'s from boot-repair, maybe will help -11779238

Comment: @oldfred I only have 5 minutes? Here Goes

Comment: One of the issues is/was that XP only works on MBR and drives over 2.2TB must be gpt partitioned. There have been several kluges by drive mfgs. to create MBR with large drives but most do not work well or prevent you from really using full size of drive. And those "fixes" do not work with Linux. Best to stay with gpt. And if you really want XP using a older smaller drive.

Answer (score 2):

> I installed Ubuntu 14.10 LTS and used the whole drive, but I don't think I chose LVM, and just formatted the whole drive as ext4, no swap or other partitions. Worked for months with no problems.

Seems all fine to me. LVM is not needed and Linux/Ubuntu will happily play along. ( [What is LVM and what is it used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for) )

> Is it possible to change back to ext4 without further damage?

Generic answer: From the Live session mount your disk and create a backup of your personal data. And then format and re-install your system. All you loose is settings and software you installed afterwards. If that includes Apache or MySQL it might be worth it saving the settings and configs from those too.

It is of course also possible to create a `dd` copy of the disk though you would need another 3Tb+ disk to store it... might be a bit too difficult.

> until one suggested I fix my errors by changing to ext2 file system.

Do not do this since it will format your disk.

> Using tools from LiveCd, PartedMagic and SysRescueCd

I have one more suggestion: [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/). Besides restoring lost files it can also repair partitions.  You can install and use it from a live session.

---

I would focus on getting a backup made from your files and then start with a clean new install.