# how to fix my partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have no idea about how i did but my partitions are mess.

I tried some solutions about similar issues which i found on ubuntu forums but no one worked.  I can not resize any of them. Can someone simply explain me what should i do now.

partitions

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa5f1e7de

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1050623      524288    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2         1050624     1550335      249856   83  Linux
/dev/sda3         1550336  1953523711   975986688   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 991.9 GB, 991940313088 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 120596 cylinders, total 1937383424 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 7457 MB, 7457472512 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 906 cylinders, total 14565376 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Comment: You are using LVM, which adds extra levels of complexity to resizing/moving partitions.  It can be more powerful, but requires special tools.  I'm not sure that the default Ubuntu enables LVM.  Do you know why you have it?  Was there a reason, or do you not know how or what you have it?

Comment: I do not know much about ubuntu so followed some instructions to install it. I do not know what LVM is and doing some research right now about it.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think the partitions are a mess?
I don't see the problem.You have a hard drive of about 1 TB and you've chosen to install the system using LVM2 Logical Volume Management. LVM are more or less dynamic partitions which you can resize or manage otherwise while the system is running. To read something about what LVM2 is see: https://askubuntu.com/a/3833/178692
So your hard drive has three station designations which are sda1, sda2 and sda3.
You have a very large volume containing the root (ubuntu--vg-root) and the remaining part of the drive contains the swap (ubuntu--vg-swap_1). Since your hard drive is filled with the volumes you'll need to shrink one first before you can enlarge the other. Since you don't show how much space is used in each one I can't give you details about shrinking.