# Space from the disk not used, how can I extend it?

Tags: partitioning, mount

Ubuntu Server and here is what I have:

When running `lsblk` I get this

```
fd0                   2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                   8:0    0  1000G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0   487M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                8:2    0     1K  0 part
└─sda5                8:5    0 199.5G  0 part
  ├─mail03--vg-root 252:0    0 126.3G  0 lvm  /
  └─mail03--vg-swap 252:1    0  65.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                   8:16   0   500G  0 disk
sr0                  11:0    1   667M  0 from
```

When running `df -h` I get this

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        900M   97M  803M  11% /run
/dev/mapper/mail03--vg-root  125G  114G  4.2G  97% /
tmpfs                        4.4G  4.0K  4.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M   44K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M  108M  340M  25% /boot
tmpfs                        900M     0  900M   0% /run/user/1000
```

sda has 1000G but the partition mounted on / has only 125G

Is it possible to extend the /dev/mapper/mail03--vg-root filesystem ?

If not can you help me please how to mount space from sda ?

I also don't want to lose any data from /dev/mapper/mail03--vg-root

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Server or a GUI?

Comment: Try and avoid pictures of text. Include the actual text in the question.

Comment: @Jeff Ubuntu server

Comment: @David Sorry it's my first posted question, I'll try to edit it

Comment: @User2692663 Okay. For a possible answer, view this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/390769/how-do-i-resize-partitions-using-command-line-without-using-a-gui-on-a-server This talks about resizing partitions, which seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks, I took a look there but still I am not sure what to run, I also don't want to lose any data from /dev/mapper/mail03--vg-root

Comment: `/dev/mapper/mail03--vg-root` means this is a LVM volume. Try to follow e.g. [Resize Ubuntu LV](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1374495)

Comment: @ridgy I am very glad that it doesn't use RAID. I think RAID would more difficult to find a decent solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1 25G` and replace `/dev/sda1` with the path to your drive. Also, replace `25G` with the size that you want. If you want it to make up the entire 1000G, replace `25G` with `1000G`. It may not allow it, because of other partitions (ex. SWAP) on the disk that take up other space. If it doesn't allow it, use the GNOME disks utility to view remaining free space and resize in regards to that. Hope this helps.