# Can't extend partition while having unallocated space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I can't seem to be able to extend a partition while having unallocated space on my drive. Firstly i tried Disks but it shows as the following:
[Tried Resizing Volume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFCd5.png)

It shows Free Space Following as 0.00 GB but i have nearly 77GB of free space
[Amount of Free Space Available but unmounted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVjEF.png)

I've also tried GParted while booting from a live USB but that also didn't work

Please Help

Comment: Hello. More info is required to help you. Lets start with what version of Ubuntu are you using? Is the empty space you are trying to use to the right of the part you are trying to extend? Have you searched this site for similar questions there are many of them?

Comment: A similar issue is on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393475/space-from-the-disk-not-used-how-can-i-extend-it/1393482#1393482

Comment: And on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/390769/how-do-i-resize-partitions-using-command-line-without-using-a-gui-on-a-server

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are trying to resize partition 5, the 20 GB ext4 partition?

The partition being extended must be contiguous with (next to) the empty space.  You will need to move about partitions on your disk to cause this to happen.

Since partitions 2 and 3 are apparently windows partitions, I would encourage you to use windows tools to move those partitions.  It is unclear what partition 4 is, but I will assume at this time this is also a windows partition.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your / mount you're trying to extend? First check:

```
    # vgdisplay
```

This should show you the name of the volume you want to extend.

For example, let's say it is mounted as /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv, you could try something like this. That's how / is mounted on my server. I recently installed a 1TB M.2 SSD on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server and it went from 100GB to 1TB! These commands will need to be run as root, or sudo'd as such...

```
    # lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

    # resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```