# Ubuntu does not use full disk space - how to extend?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 server*, and after a while got into trouble because of "no space left on device". It was only then when I realized that the Ubuntu install had not used the available disk space in full:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0   929G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

As I understand the output, the partition `nvme0n1p3` has a size of 929 GB, but Ubuntu uses only 100 GB of that. I don't know why that happened, as I have an older Ubuntu 20.04 Server installation that looks as I would expect it:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0 952.4G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 952.4G  0 lvm  /
```

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393482/657482) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/502801/657482) and tried it, but the response was:

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 929G 
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The containing partition (or device) is only 26214400 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 243531776 blocks.
```

So it tells me that the containing partition is only 100 GB in size, while `lsblk` obviously tells me something different.

How can I make Ubuntu use all of the available 929 GB?

---

*The same still happens with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS server, although I'm sure I told the installer to use all available disk space.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because Ubuntu uses an LVM volume, the size of the volume needs to be changed first before the `resize2fs` can increase the size of the underlying file system.

This can be done using `lvextend` like so:

```
$ sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 100.00 GiB (25600 extents) to <928.96 GiB (237813 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
```

The `-l +100%FREE` option tells `lvextend` to add all of the free space of the containing volume group to the logical volume.

Now we can use `resize2fs` to modify the filesystem so it uses all available space:

```
~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem at /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is mounted on /; on-line resizing required
old_desc_blocks = 13, new_desc_blocks = 117
The filesystem on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv is now 243520512 (4k) blocks long.
```

And indeed now:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0   929G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   929G  0 lvm  /
```

I found the solution at [How to resize the root LVM partition of Ubuntu](https://nekodaemon.com/2022/02/26/How-to-resize-the-root-LVM-partition-of-Ubuntu/). I recommend the article for more detailed background information.

---

You can also do the extend/resize in one step:

```bash
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. Why is this information so hard to find!? I literally searched for hours.