# Extended partition size didn't work

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

I have the following info using `df`:

```
 francis@playground  /var/log  sudo df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              595M   46M  549M   8% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   39G   39G     0 100% /
tmpfs                              3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
```

My volume group is using `/dev/sda3`.

The thing is, I enlarged the disk of this VM to 81G (it was 40GH). Then, I used fdisk to delete `/dev/sda3` and create a new partition with the new space. It worked:

```
Device       Start       End   Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      4095      2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096   2101247   2097152   1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2101248 171966430 169865183  81G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 38.97 GiB, 41821405184 bytes, 81682432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

However, I the volume group doesn't see the new space:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <38.95 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              9971
  Alloc PE / Size       9971 / <38.95 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
```

How can I get it to see the new, enlarged `/dev/sda3`?

Comment: You probably need to extend the logical volume and underlying filesystem to take advantage of the new physical volume size - see [Ubuntu does not use full disk space - how to extend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417938/ubuntu-does-not-use-full-disk-space-how-to-extend) but note that `lvextend` now has an option `-r, --resizefs` to take care of the latter automatically

Comment: @steeldriver It doesn't seem to work: 
```
sudo lvextend -l+100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv -r
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv unchanged from <38.95 GiB (9971 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
resize2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem is already 10210304 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had to extend it as directed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138090/cant-resize-a-partition-using-resize2fs

I needed to resize the physical volume first with `pvresize`. After that, the extra space became visible for the volume group/logical volume.