# Extend available disk space to Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, lvm

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04LTS on a VMWare virtual machine.
I have expanded the virtual hard disk allocated to the VM. It is now 32GB.
The size Ubuntu use is still the same (obviously).
I tried a number of answer found here. They are all similar but none worked. For example this one: [Ubuntu does not use full disk space - how to extend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417938/ubuntu-does-not-use-full-disk-space-how-to-extend).

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/ubuntu600--vg-root
```

says "New size matches existing size".

```
resize2fs dev/mapper/ubuntu600--vg-root
```

says "The file system is already 6561792 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!"

cfdisk show this:

[image]

lsblk show this:

[image]

I don't know what to do to extend Ubuntu partitions to use all available free space on disk.

Comment: It looks like you have added about a couple of G to your virtual disk and it appears at the end of the device. Your volume groups are inside an extended partition so the new free space is not available to the vg as it stands. I think the solution would be to extend sda5 to the end of the drive (sda), then the space would be available to extend the vg. You would probably need to boot the VM using a live iso containing GParted to achieve this. I’ve not used VMWare so I’m not sure how you would do that

Comment: @PonJar GParted is available on the disk. Can I use it without using another disk? That is use it on the disk Ubuntu booted with (In place partition extension).

Comment: If you run GParted from your normal installation you will probably find that the partition you want to work on will be locked. In Virtualbox you can do the following. 1. Download the GParted iso. 2. Insert the iso in a virtual CD drive. 3. Adjust boot settings to boot from the virtual CD rather than the normal disk. 4. Once GParted live has booted you can use GParted but the disk will not be locked. It is probably similar in VMWare