# My partitions disappeared after lubuntu live cd

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

My partitions disappeared after Lubuntu Live CD now there sda5 which will not mount. It was Lubuntu 14.

I looked around to see if an install is too difficult. I liked Linux puppy because was not so dangerous or difficult.

[image]

But I went back after seeing it's not for normal people.

[image]

But it didn't go back. It stayed changed from my (sda1 sda2 sda3) to sda5. I never choose or made sda5 (see picture). When I saw it looks dangerous I went back but sda5 stayed and my old partitions sda1 to sda3 didn't show up again.

In sda3 which is Packard Bell laptops windows original partit had my pics and my puppy Linux sfs collections. There was no writing action so nothing can be really deleted.

**How to get all back?** if I put puppy Linux CD in and start with puppy it is nothing there even parit5 is not to mount is the message.

[image]

Does `sudo testdisk` not work because I'm on a live CD?

I probably need a boot tool like puppy. What should I download? I have a second laptop so I can burn DVD. **What should I do to get stuff back?** The pics belong to somebody else and laptop actually too.

Comment: i must saythat my win7 in sda was not working not booting missing i just use puppy linux on this laptop with dvd its very fast

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please boot a live DVD/USB with Ubuntu (or Lubuntu or any other official Ubuntu flavour), choose the option "Try *buntu", open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run the command `sudo parted -l; sudo lsblk -f` and [edit] your question to copy and paste command output into it? Thanks.

Comment: Note that LVM is an advanced logical volume configuration that as default uses the entire hard drive erasing all other partitions. It typically has a /boot partition and entire rest of drive is one standard partition holding all the logical volumes.https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for  If not too much damage done, testdisk may find old partitions. https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Comment: SO STARTING LIVE DVD UBUNTU IS NOT DAMAGING MORE THE HARD DISK?...I STARTED LIVE CD BUT NOW I READ :

Comment: SO STARTING LIVE DVD UBUNTU IS NOT DAMAGING MORE THE HARD DISK?...I STARTED LIVE CD BUT NOW I READ :DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING ON YOUR HARDDRIVE! Don't install any software, updates or anything else, if possible don't even use Ubuntu until you recovered your data. Else, you will render yor data unrecoverable!  SO WHAT TO DO?   IS NOT POSSIBLE TO FIX BACK? I GETTING REALLY SCARED OF UBUNTU CAN JUST TELL EVERY BODYVERY UBUNTU  DANGEROUS WAS NO WARNING IF I SURE THAT WANT TO DELETE PARTITTIONS:((( SO I DELETED??

Comment: i found puppy rescue2.5  there was the test....https://photos.app.goo.gl/VXSrCmJ1Qwj5aCmg1  whAT I DO NOW JUST ENTER PRESSING ???? LOOKS QUITE SIMILAR LIKE I REMEBER JUST FIRST I THINK HAD 28 GIGA HEERE JUST 13 BUT MAYBE SOMTHING HAPPENED MEAN TIME IMPORTANT IST ONLY PACKARDBELL PART:))) WHAT TO DO :))???

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/uS7BPJq90WJ4V45D2

Comment: THE LIGHT OF HOPE  IN FINSTERNIS:)))) https://photos.app.goo.gl/uS7BPJq90WJ4V45D2

Answer (score 0):

YEAHHHHHHHHHHHHH SEEEMMM TO BE BACK

THINK  FOUND IN PUPPY FORUM :

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-data-recovery.html

PUPPY RESCUE 2.5 SELBOOTABLE dvdISO WITH TEST.. AND PROBABLY OTHER TOOLS

ALL PARTIT BACK:)))) hurrraaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

TEST... DIDINT WORKED IN LIVE LUBUNTU :(( I REMEBER SHOWED JUST MY CD ROMM NOTHING MORE!!!

but here in resckue puppy 2.5 test.. showed all deleted partit and recovered them:)))

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3286530/79c890eb5f1cd57c5c78d20c4e7f3115

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3286534/59d746f3344310f35128d52ec35ade12

http://smokey01.com/CatDude/ISOs/PupRescue/2.5/PupRescue_2.5.iso
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3286549/1570ed19b1a88f61a2720a00540537c9