# How to mount extended type partition?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I am very new to Ubuntu and running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS from bootable USB.
How can i mount sda2 or sda 5 ?

Output of `sudo fdisk -l`:

---

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB, 1591058432 bytes, 3107536 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes




Disk /dev/sda: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x08ee90aa

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 312580095 311578626 148.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 312580095 311578624 148.6G 8e Linux LVM




Disk /dev/sdb: 3.8 GiB, 4023385600 bytes, 7858175 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0033b79c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 7858174 7856127  3.8G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: You cannot. Your sda2 is an extended partition which is just a container for sda5 or other logical partiitons. And your sda5 is LVM - logical volume which gparted does not work on. LVM is an advanced partitioning used by servers and full drive encription. What is it that you want to do? If very new often better not to use LVM unless you absolutely must have encryption.  Do you have encryption? https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for

Answer (score -1):

For reasons that I forget... (IIRC has to do with how much space is allocated for the partition table on the physical disk) you can only make 4 entries in the disks partition table. Just as an MSDOS file system will only allow 512 entries in the "root" directory. To get around this restriction in MSDOS they came up with sub-directories, which were in the same format as the "root" directory with the exception that they could grow in size, as they were just files with a special attribute. Early versions of MSDOS did not have support for "sub-directories", IIRC that didn't come until MSDOS 1.6 or so.
So now we have "extended" and "LVM" types of partitions in the disks partition table to preform the same function as a sub-directory, it allows us to make more than 4 physical partitions. The physical size of the extended partition is determined by the number of logical partitions that you declare while running fdisk. It has the descriptions of the logical partition in it. A logical partition, cannot be made bootable, that is why you have to have a physical partition to boot from.

The output of sudo fdisk /dev/sda -l for my computer is below. I would recommend at least 10 Gib (some say 20) for the partition that you mount to "/". I for various reasons, like to have a separate partition for /usr (or with the 20 Gib option /usr/local) sized according to your experience and another for /home. The last one for a swap partition, sized (some say) to twice your installed RAM, I would make it so that RAM + Swap = 16 Gib for a "normal" desktop. I've had a machine running Apache, proftp as well as CAD programs and compilers running, with 12 G of RAM, run for months straight without using swap. Your mileage may vary....

Pardon the formatting of the output, this box doesn't seem to like my cut & paste!

Disk /dev/sda: 111.8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x3bec3746

Device    Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *         2048  11999231  11997184   5.7G 83 Linux

/dev/sda2        12001278 234440703 222439426 106.1G  5 Extended

/dev/sda5        12001280 111998975  99997696  47.7G 83 Linux

/dev/sda6       112001024 211998719  99997696  47.7G 83 Linux

/dev/sda7       212000768 234440703  22439936  10.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Note: sda1 is the bootable partition (physical), while sda2 is an extended partion and it IS a physical, but just describes WHERE on the disk the "extended" information is located. sda5, sda6 & sda7 are logical disks described in /sda2. What happens to sda3&4? IDK, I used to, but that was back around kernel v0.97 or so, it's been awhile.
I hope this explains whats going on here.
For further info, I'd refer to an "old skool" book (copyright 1988 Thom Hogan) named "The Programmer's PC Sourcebook", it has a table of the Disk Partition Table, with all sorts of detailed notes on offsets, etc. If you want to get down to the nitty-gritty whatsgoingonhere stuff, it's valid today, except for the legacy OS information, well, the info is still valid, but who writes software to manipulate hardware on a IBM PC/2 anymore?