# How to use 1TB harddisk in ubuntu server

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu server on my old laptop, to serve as a network share and file storage. I think I messed up the partitioning, there is a 215 Gb drive which I do not recognize.

As far as I know this laptop only has one drive of 1TB and no SSD.

The problem is samba shows me 215GB storage option only. Any suggestions?

Output of `df -h -x{tmp,devtmp,squash}fs`:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   38G  149G  21% /
/dev/sda2                          976M  206M  704M  23% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
```

[image: 215 disk]

[image: 1 TB disk]

the 999GB is `/dev/sda3`.

I read about block devices online, but I don't remember setting one up.

Comment: Is not the 215GB your LVM volumes that you have. But the LVM uses the entire sda3 partition. LVM volumes are easy to expand, so default install did not use all the available space for / & swap. https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Another new user resized LVM. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388777/how-do-i-merge-partitions-on-this-hierarchy   General info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: This is a good guide: https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/