# How do I merge partitions on this hierarchy?

Tags: boot, mount

Before describing my problem, I am a very begineer of linux file system. Therefore Important info may be missing..

Result of `lsblk` command is looks like

```
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0   930G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /. # <-- My root mount
```

I want to make 100G (`ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`) root to 930G. In other words, I want to use all nvme0n1p3 volume.
However my ubuntu system is ubuntu server which doesn't offer GUI functionality, so I can't use `gparted`.

So my question is,

1. Can I use all nvme0n1p3 partition without reinstalling whole ubuntu OS?
2. If 1 can, What should I do without using `gparted`?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by running below command

```
$ sudo lvm
lvm> lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  Size of logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv changed from 100.00 GiB (25600 extents) to <930.01 GiB (238082 extents).
  Logical volume ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv successfully resized.
lvm> exit
```

And `lsblk` command returns

```sh
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0   930G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   930G  0 lvm  /
```