# Unable to detect the programs or folders that occupy the hard drive space, and therefore unable to secure space for the genome assembly run

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive

I have an IBM server, which is installed with Ubuntu, of version 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish).

The system has two hard drives: 1. `/dev/sdb2` 2. `/dev/sdc2`. The full HDD information:
[image]

I am working on a Genome assembly project, and recently, the program got terminated due to hard drive space insufficiency. The project files are being generated in the `/dev/sdc2`. It looks like I need at least 1TB free space before the start of the assembly process. One solution that I have conceived of is to merge the two disks, and avail more free space.

Currently, I need solution to two problems:

1. In `/dev/sdb2` the free space is only 68 GB, and other documents and software have only consumed 200+ gb. I don't have any clue as to what else is eating up the hard drive space. I would like to know how I can free up more space.
2. I would like to know if someway I can re-partition the hard drive so that I have a single drive with a 2TB capacity.

Any helpful suggestions or answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is LVM and what is it used for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: Okay, I have just skimmed through it. looks like a risk of data loss involved, but nonetheless I will try that approach. In the meantime, I also like to know how I can free up more space. I am unable to find out the folders/ programs that occupy more than 600gb of the HDD.

Comment: I tried mergerfs for this purpose. Can someone help me with that? I am having a hard time installing it.